# Using multiple classes for several packages in one java file

Tags: java, android

I use several packages in my Android project.
e.x.:

> com.app.example->activities

> com.app.example->adapters

etc.

I use EventBus library (github.com/greenrobot/EventBus) where I create a CustomEvent class for each event that I use. e.x.: LogOutEvent event = new LogOutEvent(); EventBus.getDefault().post(event); If I'll have 50 events, I'll need to create 50 java files.

I can't do this because of the scopes:

```
public class Event1
{
        
}
    
class Event2
{
    
}
```

and this:

```
public class Event1
{
    
}
    
public class Event2
{
    
}
```

Comment: One top-level class per file. That's the way Java works.

Comment: I know it. But is there a correct way to store it in classes?

Comment: You haven't adequately described your problem. "Because of the scopes"? Make the classes public, like you showed, and it's fine. Name clashes? Change the names or use fully-qualified.

Comment: Edited my question

Comment: You still haven't provided a rationale other than "there will be lots of files", which is the way Java is written.

Comment: Should I create so many files for this?

Comment: Yes; it's not at all uncommon to have lots of files for various events. A small application I'm working on has 20 DTO classes, each in a file.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't work with the library you mentioned before but I think It's all about design principles, so why not using **static nested classes** like this:

```
public class Events {
   // Try to write your global/common methods here
   public void stop(){

   }
   public void start(){

   }
    
    // your Inner classes
    public static class Event1 { }
    public static class Event2 { }
    public static class Event3 { }
    public static class Event4 { }
    public static class Event5 { }
}
```

OR using Java 8:

```
public interface IEvents {
    default void start(){

    }

    default void stop(){

    }
}

public class EventsImpl implements IEvents{

    // your Inner classes
    public static class Event1 { }
    public static class Event2 { }
    public static class Event3 { }
    public static class Event4 { }
    public static class Event5 { }
}
```

Memory leak is for Non-static inner classes, and the example above use weaker reference to achieve cleaner memory management **(static inner classes).** Check [this](https://dzone.com/articles/a-troublesome-legacy-memory-leaks-in-java) for more details.

You can also change the scope of your inner classes the way you want.

I highly recommend you to think more about the problematic you have, and the design principles you can work with. For example try thinking about all your global methods of each Event, so you don't write classes with the same events methods.

Comment: I know it too:) My main problem is that I need to save classes with Events and use it in various packages.

Comment: I don't know about how much classes you need, but why not creating more java class files ? 'save classes with Events' what do you mean ? please describe more your problem

Comment: I use EventBus library (https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus) where I create a CustomEvent class for each event that I use. e.x.: LogOutEvent event = new LogOutEvent(); EventBus.getDefault().post(event);

If I'll have 50 events, I'll need to create 50 java files.

Comment: Can I get the memory leak problem using static classes like this? With EventBus I must create objects like this: Events.Event1 event = new Events.Event1();

Comment: I edited my post: memory leak is for Non-static inner classes, and the example above use weaker reference to achieve cleaner memory management (static) so there is no risk